# Can't discover Unit test after change to .net6, TestPlatformException: System.MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

After I have changed the solution from net472 to .net6, the VS Test Explorer can't detect any tests. I can see them in the test explorer, but when I start a test run, I get the message that no test is detected.

In the output of the test's I can see this error:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: The test host process terminated with an error: Unhandled Exception. System.MissingMethodException: method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.TestHostManagerFactory..ctor(Boolean)'.

But I don't know how to fix this (and haven't found anything on the web).

What I tried:

- Update VS Studio to the latest version (VS Enterprise 2022, 17.2.5).
- Uninstall and reinstall all Nuget packages (latest version installed).
- Check target platforms
- Run tests on another system

I appreciate any other suggestions for solutions!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In my experience usually this means that you have some nuget packages version mismatch for example two packages use different versions of the same package and only one (obviously) is installed and it have the method in question removed/changed signature. Can you please share your .csproj or part with referenced nuget packages or share [mre]?

Comment: Thanks... Got a version little version missmatch... No it's running!